# Nagios check unknown custom script

Tags: linux, nagios

I have bash script that returns right results when I run as user nagios manually. It fails as unknown when configured in in nagios configs.

Entries in nagios configs

```
 define command { 
     command_name   check_s3descrepency
     command_line /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_s3descrepency $ARG1$

 }

define service{
        use                     generic-service
        service_description     Check android_event S3 descrepency
        host_name               nagios-server
        check_command       check_s3descrepency!android_event
}

[root@nagios nagios]# sudo -u nagios /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_s3descrepency android_event
OK - 2014-05-07-22-00 Data size match with pre week 2014-04-30-22-00 by 102%
[root@nagios nagios]#
```

Enabled  the debug and following is the log

```
[1399529584.757820] [016.0] [pid=1089] Checking service 'Check android_event S3 descrepency' on host 'nagios-server'...
[1399529584.757839] [2320.2] [pid=1089] Raw Command Input: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_s3descrepency $ARG1$
[1399529584.757891] [2320.2] [pid=1089] Expanded Command Output: /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_s3descrepency $ARG1$
[1399529584.757916] [2048.1] [pid=1089] Processing: '/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_s3descrepency $ARG1$'
[1399529584.757923] [2048.2] [pid=1089]   Processing part: '/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_s3descrepency '
[1399529584.757930] [2048.2] [pid=1089]   Not currently in macro.  Running output (46): '/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_s3descrepency '
[1399529584.757957] [2048.2] [pid=1089]   Uncleaned macro.  Running output (66): '/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_s3descrepency android_event'
[1399529584.757962] [2048.2] [pid=1089]   Just finished macro.  Running output (66): '/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_s3descrepency android_event'
[1399529584.757972] [2048.2] [pid=1089]   Not currently in macro.  Running output (66): '/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_s3descrepency android_event'
[1399529584.757977] [2048.1] [pid=1089]   Done.  Final output: '/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_s3descrepency android_event'
[1399529586.011991] [016.1] [pid=1089] Handling check result for service 'Check android_event S3 descrepency' on host 'nagios-server'...
[1399529586.012012] [016.0] [pid=1089] ** Handling check result for service 'Check android_event S3 descrepency' on host 'nagios-server'...
[1399529586.012022] [016.1] [pid=1089] HOST: nagios-server, SERVICE: Check android_event S3 descrepency, CHECK TYPE: Active, OPTIONS: 1, SCHEDULED: Yes, RESCHEDULE: Yes, EXITED OK: Yes, RETURN CODE: 3, OUTPUT: \nUNKNOWN - 2014-05-07-22-00 Data size match with pre week 2014-04-30-22-00 by %\n
[1399529586.012170] [016.1] [pid=1089] Checking service 'Check android_event S3 descrepency' on host 'nagios-server' for flapping...
[1399529586.012267] [032.0] [pid=1089] ** Service Notification Attempt ** Host: 'nagios-server', Service: 'Check android_event S3 descrepency', Type: 0, Options: 0, Current State: 3, Last Notification: Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 1969
[1399529586.012385] [016.0] [pid=1089] Scheduling a non-forced, active check of service 'Check android_event S3 descrepency' on host 'nagios-server' @ Wed May  7 23:23:04 2014
[1399529631.103930] [008.0] [pid=1089] ** Service Check Event ==> Host: 'nagios-server', Service: 'Check android_event S3 descrepency', Options: 0, Latency: 0.103000 sec
[1399529631.103946] [016.0] [pid=1089] Attempting to run scheduled check of service 'Check android_event S3 descrepency' on host 'nagios-server': check options=0, latency=0.103000
```

Comment: Check your script for things related to the environment (PATH, etc).

Comment: Nagios use `return code` to determined the state of command (OK, Warning, critical, unknown) see [documentation](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html). Please post the return codes of the script after executed in shell. References in [how-to-check-exit-status-code](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/03/how-to-check-exit-status-code.html)

Comment: You spelled discrepancy wrong ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Zoredache. It was env variable.

s3cmd was not in path for nagios user, Added full path in script and it worked like charm.